# printing a variable in python

Tags: python, class, printing

I have this python code which set A or B in a class. I want to print what this class receives:

```
if options.A:
   print "setting A"
   class TmpClass(A): pass
else:
   print "nothing set in the command line => setting to B"
   class TmpClass(B): pass

print "selected=",TmpClass
```

I want to see either A or B in the output but I see:

```
selected= TmpClass
```

Comment: This looks really weird. Are you quite sure you know what you are doing? If not, please research OOP again, because apparently you did not understand the concept.

Comment: Do you have two classes `A` and `B`? Because what you are doing is creating a new class `TmpClass` that inherits from either `A` or `B`.

Comment: Sorry.... That question does not represent my problem. I will try to edit it soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your code is doing, translated in English is:

```
if option.A has a value that evaluates to True:
    define an empty class called "TmpClass" that inherits from the object called "A"
otherwise:
    define an empty class called "TmpClass" that inherits from the object called "B"
```

Now, **if** what the code is actually doing is indeed what you intended, my *guess* is that what you wanted could be to know whether your class is A or B -based... If I am right, then the line you want to have at the end is:

```
print('TmpClass inherits from : %s' % TmpClass.__bases__)
```

HTH!

Comment: brilliant... that was exactly what I meant :)

Answer (score 1):

You can assign classes to a variable, without creating instances of them:

```
if options.A:
   print "setting A"
   TmpClass = A
else:
   print "nothing set in the command line => setting to B"
   TmpClass = B

print "selected=",TmpClass
```

Answer (score 1):

You might look at using isinstance().  For example:

```
class MyBaseClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cType = 'Base'

    def whichClass(self):
        print 'Class type = {0}'.format(self.cType)

        if isinstance(self,DerivedClassA):
            print 'Derived Class A'
        elif isinstance(self,DerivedClassB):
            print 'Derived Class B'
        elif isinstance(self,MyBaseClass):
            print 'Not A or B'
        else:
            print 'Unknown Class'

class DerivedClassA(MyBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cType = 'Class A'

class DerivedClassB(MyBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cType = 'Class B'


Then Run:

base = MyBaseClass()
a = DerivedClassA()
b = DerivedClassB()
a.whichClass()
>> Class type = Class A
>> Derived Class A
b.whichClass()
>> Class type = Class B
>> Derived Class B
base.whichClass()
>> Class type = Base
>> Not A or B
```

Answer (score 0):

A and B are formal arguments passed to the class here, not actual values of A and B.